# Can not sync files on network while using Microsoft Sync Framework on two different machines

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to use MS sync framework on network. But it is giving me an exception Could not find a part of the path. Can anyone please tell me how can I make the connection on network in order to sync two folders on different computers over network.
I can access the folder from my explorer fine so no issue in sharing or permissions. I am in the same wifi network. I have a clue that maybe I have to enter credentials somehow.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     
           FileSyncProvider sourceReplica = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), @"E:\test");
            FileSyncProvider destReplica = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), @"\\192.168.1.9\New Folder"); //Here I am getting exception.
  
            SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
            agent.LocalProvider = sourceReplica;
            agent.RemoteProvider = destReplica;
            agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;
            agent.Synchronize();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So after spending a lot of time I finally sound a solution. Actually the problem was With credentials. So I researched online and find a solution for that.

I copied a file from an answer which is like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace syncDemo
{
    class ConnectToSharedFolder :IDisposable
    {
        readonly string _networkName;

        public ConnectToSharedFolder(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)
        {
            _networkName = networkName;

            var netResource = new NetResource
            {
                Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
                ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
                DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
                RemoteName = networkName
            };

            var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
                ? credentials.UserName
                : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

            var result = WNetAddConnection2(
                netResource,
                credentials.Password,
                userName,
                0);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");
            }
        }

        ~ConnectToSharedFolder()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
        }

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
            string password, string username, int flags);

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
            bool force);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class NetResource
        {
            public ResourceScope Scope;
            public ResourceType ResourceType;
            public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
            public int Usage;
            public string LocalName;
            public string RemoteName;
            public string Comment;
            public string Provider;
        }

        public enum ResourceScope : int
        {
            Connected = 1,
            GlobalNetwork,
            Remembered,
            Recent,
            Context
        };

        public enum ResourceType : int
        {
            Any = 0,
            Disk = 1,
            Print = 2,
            Reserved = 8,
        }

        public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
        {
            Generic = 0x0,
            Domain = 0x01,
            Server = 0x02,
            Share = 0x03,
            File = 0x04,
            Group = 0x05,
            Network = 0x06,
            Root = 0x07,
            Shareadmin = 0x08,
            Directory = 0x09,
            Tree = 0x0a,
            Ndscontainer = 0x0b
        }
    }
}
```

And in my main form, I did this.

```
public string networkPath = @"\\{I.P}\New Folder";
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"userName", "password");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FileSyncProvider sourceReplica = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), @"E:\test");
            FileSyncProvider destReplica;
            using (new ConnectToSharedFolder(networkPath, credentials))
            {
               destReplica = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), @"\\192.168.1.9\New Folder");
            }
            
            SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
            agent.LocalProvider = sourceReplica;
            agent.RemoteProvider = destReplica;
            agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;
            agent.Synchronize();

        }
```